# Using While in a sentence

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

Today when I was watching Impractical Jokers, in an episode one of the guys was tasked  with "hit on a girl while wearing a skirt and heels".

Is it me or  "**while**" here seems redundant? If I remove it then the sentence would be "**hit on a girl wearing heels**.

Do these both have the same meaning or there is a nuance of difference?

Answer (score 3):

If a man is tasked with **hitting on a girl while wearing a skirt and heels**, that means **the man** has to be wearing a skirt and heels at the time he does the hitting-on.

If he has to **hit on a girl, wearing a skirt and heels**, that means the above. Note comma.

If he has to **hit on a girl wearing a skirt and heels**, that means that the girl has to be wearing a skirt and heels.

Comment: +1 The 'while' removes any ambiguity

Answer (score 2):

> Hit on a girl wearing a skirt and heels.

To me it sounds like asking someone to hit on a girl who is wearing skirt and heels.

Now

> Hit on a girl while wearing a skirt and heels.

Here it's specified that someone is being asked to hit on a girl while that person is wearing skirt and heels, not the girl